# How I set the memory configuration in OrientDB

Tags: memory, orientdb

I have a computer with

**Processor: i7 2.60 GHz**,

**16 GB Ram**,

**64-bit OS**

How can I set the memory configuration in **OrientDB**?

Can someone help me ?

Where and how please.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Configuration.html

Comment: I read but I did not understand How I need to do, sorry I am new very new in this topic

Comment: There are several different ways to do it, by Java, console .... from Java and Console you have to run the command written in the guide, while from server configuration you have to open the file orientdb-server-config.xml (or orientdb-dserver-config.xml) and add the snippet code present in the guide between the <properties> section. You have to choose one of the possibilities listed in the guide, if you need to change the memory settings, otherwise you will use the default values.

Comment: Take a look at: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Performance-Tuning.html#server-and-embedded-settings